# Can you suggest any online JSON Grid Viewer or table viewer?

Tags: javascript, json, json.net, jsonp, json-view

I looked over many online JSON Viewer, but none of them are really good, in terms of showing JSON arrays in table format. Please suggest if you know.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one, it's really awesome. Cleanest JSON Grid Viewer I ever saw.

http://www.jsongrid.com/